# How to use socket.io in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io

I am creating an app in ionic using **cordova** and **angular**.

I have to make a request using ip address and port no. to socket.

I have read about socket.io. and I am confused about how to install **socket.io** along with how to use with angular js and node.js?
I am using angular-socket-io library to get socket  datafrom yahoo server
    created this factory in app.js

```
.factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:10001');
    mySocket = socketFactory({ioSocket: myIoSocket});
   return mySocket;
});
```

How to get return data in controller when the page load for the first time?

Comment: check this wrapper for socket.io for angular https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io and also this tutorial http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: I have used angular-socket-io Now i am confused how to make request to server

Comment: This is pretty straight forward... https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#user-content-socketfactory-iosocket-

Comment: @MuliYulzary I am also facing problem in using socket.io. I am planing to do a chat in my existing project but i am not able to understand how to implement chat using socket.io

Comment: Their tutorial is very clear. what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: how to get data and show using angular-socket-io

Comment: @MuliYulzary is there any video tutorial for working with socket.io in ionic can you reffer me with working example in video

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but this one's good in my opinion and is in Angular so you can easily implement this later in ionic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LkheOr8LuY

Comment: @MuliYulzary check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894118/how-to-develop-a-chat-application-between-two-users-or-creating-a-group-for-chat and also while commenting please mention my name so that i can get any notification

Comment: It is removed recently I think before half an hour. I have opened page still in my broser.